# How can I add to $PATH with tox?

Tags: python, django, testing, protractor, tox

I'm using tox to run protractor tests which will test an application which uses django+angularjs, there is a glue library (django-protractor) which makes this easier, except that it makes the call to protractor inside a django management command, and relies on $PATH to show it where protractor is.

So if I set the $PATH properly before running tox, it works fine, but I'd rather not require all the devs to do that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you modify your path in the `manage.py` file to include `django-protractor` directory, because the Django management command line uses `manage.py`.

Comment: @Lefunque please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful for you by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 7):

To use environment variables tox provides the syntax `{env:VARIABLE}`. To set them tox provides the `setenv` section.

These can be used together to modify the PATH variable that can be used by commands:

```
[testenv]
setenv =
  PATH = {env:PATH}{:}/path/to/protractor

commands = 
  echo {env:PATH}
```

Another option that might work in some cases is symlink or download the binary in a writable path of the PATH, hopefully we always have one available: the virtual environments' binary folder, which is `{envbindir}` in tox.

Comment: I'm not sure PATH can be setenv. I've been trying it with unpromising results :( @undu, did you test it?

Comment: Just tried it: It works as expected for me on Linux.

Comment: I've set up a repo with travis to show that it works:
https://travis-ci.com/undu/tox-path-example/jobs/136762405
Note the /path/to/protractor just before the summary

The tox configuration can be found here: https://github.com/undu/tox-path-example/blob/master/tox.ini